# Is there WSOP (or other organisation) Texas Hold-em chip and blind schedule?

Tags: poker, poker-texas-holdem

Is there a WSOP (or other organisation) agreed hold-'em tournament set-up for chips and blinds schedule:

e.g. something that lays out:

**Chips arrangement:**
Players start with 2000 worth of chips:
200 in 5
200 in 10
500 in 25
600 in 50
500 in 100

**Blinds schedule:**
5-10
10-20
20-40
25-50
30-60
50-100
100-200
200-400
250-500 (max)

**Blind increase:**
Blinds increase every 15 minutes/per knock out?

Do any sites recommend set-ups for home games for varying numbers of players (under 10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blind structure depends strongly on too many factors to have a standard structure. Most importantly it depends on the chip values you use.

You can look at the offical WSOP structure on it's site: http://www.wsop.com/tournaments/ (The "Structure Sheet" links)